# How to pass a Model from page to page in Blazor without using a service?

Tags: blazor-server-side

I need to pass a Model I create in one page to another, But I don't want to create a service for it. Is there any feature in Blazor that I can use other than services?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I know you are asking about doing this without a service but I think a service is the way to go to persist state for a user.

1) create your service class (ex: AppState).

```
public class AppState
{
    public YourSpecialModel model {get; set}
}
```

2) Register your service either as a singleton or Scoped in your Startup.cs:

```
 services.AddScoped<AppState>();
```

3) Inject your service on the pages you need

```
  [Inject]
    protected AppState appState { get; set; }
```

4) Set and get your model from your appState across all pages.